# Compiler error: "format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’"

Tags: c

The program takes a 9-word long code (For example: `011112222`). The first number is the code for the operation (0 for `+`, 1 for `-`, 2 for `*`, 3 for `/`) the next 4 numbers are the first number and the other 4 are the other number so for `011112222` the result should be `1111+2222`. This is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

float* Calculate(char* buffer)
{
    int number1, number2;
    
    char *firstPart = (char *)malloc(strlen(buffer));
    char *secondPart = (char *)malloc(strlen(buffer));

    strncpy(firstPart, buffer+1, 4);
    strncpy(secondPart, buffer+5, 8);

    number1 = atoi(firstPart);
    number2 = atoi(secondPart);

    float *result;

    if( buffer[0] == '0')
    {
        *result = (float)number1 + (float)number2;
    }
    else if(buffer[0] == '1')
    {
        *result = (float)number1 - (float)number2;
    }
    else if(buffer[0] == '2')
    {
        *result = (float)number1 * (float)number2;
    }
    else if(buffer[0] == '3')
    {
        *result = (float)number1 / (float)number2;
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    char buffer[20];
    printf("Insert code word: ");
    scanf("%s", buffer);

    float *result = Calculate(buffer);
    printf("%f", result);
    
    return 1;
}
```

But I get this error:

```
In function ‘main’:
    zadatak.c:54:14: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘float *’ [-Wformat=]
        printf("%f", result);
```

What is causing this warning and how can I resolve it?

Comment: `printf("%f", result);` -->`printf("%f", *result);` Also you have undefined behavior as you are de-referencing `result` without valid memory

Comment: I tried that but I get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" xD

Comment: Why is `result` a pointer at all?

Comment: Because `result` is pointing to nowhere.

Comment: Because of  float* Calculate(char* buffer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `printf` call:

```
printf("%f", result);
```

The `%f` format specifier expects a `double` (or a `float` which gets automatically converted), but you're passing it a **pointer** to a float.  You need to dereference the pointer to get the `float` value:

```
printf("%f", *result);
```

**However**, you have another problem.

Inside of `Calculate` you define `result`, which is what you return from the function, as a pointer to a `float`, but you never set it to point anywhere.  So anytime you try do dereference this pointer you're reading an uninitialized value and using it as a valid pointer.  Doing so invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

There's no reason to use a pointer to a `float` in your code, so change both `result` in `main` and `result` in `Calculate` from `float *` to `float`, and change `Calculate` to return a `float`.

Also, the `strncpy` function doesn't always null terminate the destination string, and `malloc` returns uninitialized memory, so `atoi` will can read past the end of allocated memory when it reads the strings.  You can fix this by using `calloc` instead of `malloc` which returns memory initialized to all 0's.  Also, be sure to `free` those buffers when you're done with them.

```
float Calculate(char* buffer)
{
    int number1, number2;

    char *firstPart = calloc(strlen(buffer), 1);
    char *secondPart = calloc(strlen(buffer), 1);

    strncpy(firstPart, buffer+1, 4);
    strncpy(secondPart, buffer+5, 8);

    number1 = atoi(firstPart);
    number2 = atoi(secondPart);

    free(firstPart);
    free(secondPart);

    float result;

    if( buffer[0] == '0')
    {
        result = (float)number1 + (float)number2;
    }
    else if(buffer[0] == '1')
    {
        result = (float)number1 - (float)number2;
    }
    else if(buffer[0] == '2')
    {
        result = (float)number1 * (float)number2;
    }
    else if(buffer[0] == '3')
    {
        result = (float)number1 / (float)number2;
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    char buffer[20];
    printf("Insert code word: ");
    scanf("%s", buffer);

    float result = Calculate(buffer);
    printf("%f", result);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I see that you removed a pointer from the function, it supposed to be float* Calculate(char * buffer). Why?

Comment: @Stefan There's no need for a pointer to be returned.  The function can simply return a `float` value.

Comment: I just asked because in the text of this assignment  the name of the function contained the pointer that is why asked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Stefan If the assignment requires this function to return a pointer, then allocate memory for `result` in `Calculate`, and change the `printf` line in `main` to dereference the pointer.

Comment: That is the answer I wanted, so I needed to allocate memory for the result, know I understand. Thanks again @dbush, for you help!

Comment: @Stefan the requirement of the assignment sounds fishy

Comment: @Stefan May I ask why you unaccepted this answer more than 2 years later?

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs many validations and changes to be reliable, but i made few changes to reach your initial purpose.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

float Calculate(char* buffer)
{
    int number1, number2;

    char *firstPart = (char *)malloc(strlen(buffer));
    char *secondPart = (char *)malloc(strlen(buffer));
    float result;

    strncpy(firstPart, buffer + 1, 4);
    strncpy(secondPart, buffer + 5, 4);
    number1 = atoi(firstPart);
    number2 = atoi(secondPart);


    if( buffer[0] == '0')
    {
        result = (float)number1 + (float)number2;
    }
    else if(buffer[0] == '1')
    {
        result = (float)number1 - (float)number2;
    }
    else if(buffer[0] == '2')
    {
        result = (float)number1 * (float)number2;
    }
    else if(buffer[0] == '3')
    {
        result = (float)number1 / (float)number2;
    }

    free(firstPart);
    free(secondPart);

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    char buffer[20];
    printf("Insert code word: ");
    scanf("%s", buffer);

    float result = Calculate(buffer);
    printf("%f", result);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Code without explanation is not an appropriate answer.